# Reading excel file in c#.net cell by cell

Tags: c#, database, excel, import

I'm new to `c#.net`

I have excel sheet and I want to import into `database`.

I want to read it cell by cell and want to insert value in `database`.

```
this.openFileDialog1.FileName = "*.xls";
            DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=no;IMEX=1;""", openFileDialog1.FileName);
                string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", "Sheet3");

                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connectionString);

                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Can you give some detail around what the code above does, or doesn't do? It's also not a complete code sample, the end of the if block is not supplied nor anything that happens after.

Comment: You've told what you want. Now what's the quesion?

Comment: just i want to take cell value in variable

Comment: You have your dataset, just enumerate row-by-row and cell-by-cell and do what you want

Comment: you need to iterate through the dataSet.Tables[0] and and get value of the each cells in each row to find the values, then you can put them to database by writing another insert function. Is that something you want? if so, I can provide the code.

Comment: but for that i dont know code

Comment: In that case you should probably take a tutorial on c#

Comment: @annonymously: Well, that's why he said he's new to C#. Comments like yours wont help him at all.

Comment: I'm sick of comments on this website that aren't constructive. If I didn't have a life I'd probably flag the lot of them if I could. He's new, stop grilling him - I don't care how high your rep is - smarmy comments and patronising attitudes don't help anybody.

Comment: In answer to your question bkac - I believe Thorsten Dittmar's suggestion has nailed it. Good luck mate, and try to keep your questions a bit more specific if you can, even if it means you making several questions.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArpYU-n8THyLdG1CUktDRGtIdEE0N0tDTHp3akRXenc  see this file i want to import this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that after you execute the code in your question, you can see the values within `dataGridView1`.

The actual reading from the excel sheet is done when calling `dataAdapter.Fill`. So, in your case, reading the cells comes down to indexing columns and rows in `dataSet.Tables[0]`.

For example:

```
for (int row = 0; row < dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; row++)
{
   DataRow r = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[row];
}
```

Accessing the cells in row `r` is trivial (like the sample above, just for cell).

**EDIT**
I forgot to describe the "insert the values into a database" part. I presume that the database is SQL Server (may be Express edition, too).

First: create a database connection. Instead of manually composing the connection string, use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.DataSource = <your server instance, e.g. "localhost\sqlexpress">;
csb.InitialCatalog = <name of your database>;
csb.IntegratedSecurity = <true if you use integrated security, false otherwise>;
if (!csb.IntegratedSecurity)
{
    csb.UserId = <User name>;
    csb.Password = <Password>;
}
```

Then, create and open a new `SqlConnection` with the connection string:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
```

Iterate over all the values you want to insert and execute a respective insert command:

```
    for (...)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (@param1, ..., @paramn)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", value1);
        ...
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramn", valuen);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

This closes the connection, as the `using` block ends:

```
}
```

And there you go. Alternatively, you could use a data adapter with a special insert-command. Then, inserting the values would come down to a one-liner, however, your database table must have the same structure as the Excel-sheet (respectively: as the data table you obtained in the code you posted.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ArpYU-n8THyLdG1CUktDRGtIdEE0N0tDTHp3akRXenc

Comment: check above file i want to import

Comment: The real question is: Does the code you posted in your question display anything in the `DataGridView`? If so, just do as I said in my reply and iterate over the rows and columns.

Comment: DataGridView it for just my refrance

Comment: You can access the value of an individual column in a `DataRow` through `row[cellIndex]` or `row["columnName"]`. See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx

Comment: The reason I asked whether anything was in the `DataGridView` is to find out whether the Excel sheet is read properly. If there's nothing in the `DataGridView`, the code for filling the `DataSet` doesn't work properly. If you see the contents of the Excel sheet in your `DataGridView`, valid data is read into the `DataSet` and things should work as I described.

Answer (score 1):

Check out NPOI

http://npoi.codeplex.com/

It's the .NET version of Apache's POI Excel implementation.  It'll easily do what you need it to do, and will help avoid some of the problems ( i.e. local copy of Excel, or worse, copy of Excel on the server ) that you'll face when using the Jet provider.

Comment: An Excel installation is not required when accessing the Excel sheet through the ODBC driver.

Comment: Fair enough, but there are some bloody awful parts about the ODBC driver, such as the inferring of type.

Comment: In the end it doesn't really matter whether the ODBC driver infers types badly or whether Excel does it wrong - I must admit, however, that with Excel, Microsoft have wrapped a pretty nice GUI around bad type inference.